# Dragon ball super: ep 92 What theme is playing at 21:10?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-super

In ep 92 of DBS, around the 21st minute, a theme starts playing, and I can't find it.  I have heard it in previous episodes as well, but I cant remember where. I was hoping someone here might know.

Answer (score 0):

So i listened to all 140 themes of DBS and found nothing then my small brain finally decided to use shazam and found the theme its the theme of super saiyan 3 and  the reason i couldn't find it is becouse it is originating from dragon ball kai.

Hope you enjoy the theme